# iOS 8 - How to get LocalNotification playing Sound when App is in Background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, avplayer

I need to have some Alarm-Clock Functionality in my App.

One of them should be to let the Phone playing Sound when the LocalNotification fires and the App is in the Background.

With iOS 7.1 everything works fine but in iOS8 no Sound is playing anymore until the App is back in Foreground.

At the Moment i'm using the `AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h` Class.

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Did you register for local notification using `registerUserNotificationSettings` .

Comment: @Bhumit: Yes, that way: `
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];}`

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{
if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
          NSLog(@"Denied");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Granted");
    }


}

Comment: Con you confirm you are being granted permissions in delegate call back by using above method?

Comment: @Bhumit: I did also check under Background Modes —> Check: Modes: Audio and AirPlay and made Settings to the app.plist

Comment: @Bhumit: I run this Code: `UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) { NSLog(@"Denied"); } else{ NSLog(@"Granted"); }` and get "Granted". So that seems to be ok.

Comment: show the code where you set up the notification with sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug within Xcode Simulator for iOS8. 
With Xcode Simulator for iOS7.1 AND/OR iOS8 "real" Device everything works fine.

Comment: After spending hours trying to figure out why sound is not working, 3 different machines (all in simulator). Finally, tested on a real device and sound is working. Was simply hard to believe that on Xcode 6.4 at this late time something like this is broken. In short, I can (somewhat) verify that it's an iOS 8 simulator bug.

Answer (score 2):

This code may be help you...

#### Register Notification Settings

#### - for Objective c

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]

        return YES;
    }
```

#### - for Swift

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool 
    {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound|UIUserNotificationType.Alert |UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil)   

        return true
    }
```

Comment: that's what i wrote before. see my comment to Bhumit.

Answer (score 0):

.caf fine doesn't play with local notification on real device. If you change .caf to .aiff you'll notification with sound!